# Laravel Artisan Console Command - Input Limits

Tags: php, laravel, terminal

I have an artisan command which prompts the user for a long token string:

```
public function handle()
{
    $name = $this->ask('What is your token?');
}
```

I'd like to paste the following into the command:

```
e1yJraWQiOiJacmRwRFwvMTdDUFRBcytpT3ZZQ2V0WGc2Q0IrUFd3a3NmYjdwNktFT29JZz0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.OD9WO9Msxv664SWSSSB-yABL9E-j0lGRGgZTtXVg5RZu-wVTrMAmxR--k7rsqo_AFSbN80u8oqIhuuKO7jeMNCk-rmzdKRjJbqxRnnfN9kR9redhpKPL15bFUZlJwK6RiODG6PFBh8ZETWl9B76Z3wlncIHWOARLTKVjXkPrdxaumlwYBurfoOJWLsNBexK8ORYWYV_WRcnOtUeDwLd_dahTeMRMNBK4Pu1bxPY0L0SBsdJQE3Y_Jbv4oD7cLepDTjJhUM2kPes12n4xgM3a4laSfNuHILT6wRbPm925eV-vpgeyiPYDEOMSDkCy1gPhs6du3aMspjQq1bPjWc7qV7uCsupkgr5478hHsd7834ghJD
```

But when I try to paste in the entire string, it truncates the string and I'm unable to paste the entire string, which effectively makes the command useless. Any advice on how I can get it to be able to paste the entire string?

**Versions**

- PHP 7.4 (Using [PHP Monitor](https://github.com/nicoverbruggen/phpmon))
- Laravel 5.8
- Running on Valet

**What I've tried**

I'm currently using iTerm and I can successfully paste the entire string into just the command prompt. My issue seems to happen only when prompting from a Laravel command.

I've also changed the command to use arguments such as `command:token {token}` (as suggested by @MichaelMano in the comments below). This approach works, but it would be a better user experience to ask for the token rather than require the user to remember to include the token when executing the command. If possible, I'd still like to use the ask method to get the token from the user.

Comment: are you able to use it as an argument or does it have to be set via the cli? e.g. `protected $signature = 'command:token {token}';` then. `$this->argument('token');`

Comment: @MichaelMano, excellent suggestion! Yes, it does work if I make the token an argument. There are tons of ways to get around the limitations of the ask method but I'd prefer it if the command asked the user for the token. Do you know how to lift the limit for the ask method?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Laravel 9.11 with two different terminal emulators on Ubuntu 18.04. For me it seems to be working just fine. Can you please edit the question and add some more potentially relevant information about your project, such as the Laravel version you're working with?

Comment: It happens on mine, MacOS with iterm2 and default term, I figured it was the limitations of the PHP IO

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @PietervandenHam. I've updated the question to show the versions used in the app I'm working on.